# How can i share image using sharer.php of Facebook

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I want to share image using sharer facebook. I am doing like this below.

```
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100
            &p[url]=http://ar.zu.my
            &p[images][0]=https://drupal.org/files/Share_2.jpg&p[title]=Rock on Arzumy"> Share button</a>
```

Other things working fine. pop up shows up for share but there is no image for sharing in

share pop up. So everything except than image share properly.

But it is not working...

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: We need more infromation. What have you tried so far? What exactly happens when you click on the link?

Comment: @marvelousNinja  Any thing working fine. pop up shows up for share but there is no image for sharing in share pop up.

Comment: Have you tried to share different image (I mean, from different url).

Comment: @marvelousNinja  Yes, try all option but sharer.php has serious problem with share image